# MLP Classifier in SKlearn to include "softmax" activation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network, mlp

I am trying to fit MLP model but I would like to use 'SOFTMAX' as an output layer. Could you please let me know how can I incorporate the same?

Comment: If you could provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see what exactly you're struggling with? That would be helpful.

Comment: mlp = MLPClassifier(max_iter = 500, activation = 'softmax', hidden_layer_sizes = (100,50,25))                                                                               mlp.fit(X_train,y_train)                                                                                                KeyError: 'softmax'. I know in SKLearn there is no activation function as Softmax. I want to define a soft-max at the output layer and a cross-entropy
loss function to perform classification.

Comment: I can't reach scikit-learn.org rn for some reason, but I guess MLPClassifier implies softmax activation on the last layer by default. You're setting only hidden layers' activations

Answer (score 1):

"softmax can be used as an output function within sklearn as follow.

mlp.out_activation_='softmax'